# UCHAR or WCHAR for communication buffer

Tags: c++, c, buffer

I have a buffer:

```
typedef struct _MESSAGE {
    UCHAR Data[];
} MESSAGE, *PMESSAGE;
```

That is used for communication(to pass parametrs, like ulong) between driver and user mode app. I used it as UCHAR type. But now i want also send wide characters with this buffer, should i change it type
to WCHAR or PCHAR?

What data type is better suite here?

Comment: Are you programming in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change data type, it is a generic byte (a raw data stream type). Try this it work:

```
    typedef struct _MESSAGE {
    UCHAR Data[200];
} MESSAGE_T, *PMESSAGE_T;

int byte_offset = 0;    // byte offset inside your data stream

wchar_t MyMessage1[] = L"Ciao Mondo";
wchar_t MyMessage2[100];

MESSAGE_T Message;

// write message1 in the data stream
wcscpy( (wchar_t*)&Message.Data[byte_offset], MyMessage1);

// read message from the data stream
wcscpy( MyMessage2, (wchar_t*)&Message.Data[byte_offset]);

// TESTED AND WORK!
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not use a byte array? `BYTE*` ? Also if I recall correcly, you could pass a void* to the driver and read it as a struct there.